# Optimize MYSQL+PHP parent-children output

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, optimization, grouping

I'm just trying to find a way to make a server-resource effective way of sorting and showing alphabetically sorted parent/children structure. I'm not a professional programmer so my code below is lame, but it works and maybe you can help me to optimize it.

the table is

**id, parentid, name.**

parentid is 0 for parents and =id for children.

the task is to show alphabetically sorted parents and all children under their parents, also alphabetically sorted. All items should have names and their corresponding ids. The structure is like this:

```
AAA
BBB
-> eee of BBB
-> ooo of BBB
-> zzz of BBB
CCC
DDD
-> mmm of DDD
-> nnn of DDD
EEE
FFF
...
```

This is my stupid code, however, it works. MySQL sorts all items alphabetically and PHP just loops through already sorted names, selecting and showing children for every parent.
I don't like that additional loop that runs for every parent item, maybe someone can suggest **a better way in terms of performance**?

```
$sqlquer="SELECT id, parentid, name FROM mytable ORDER BY name";
    $ath = mysql_query($sqlquer);

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($ath)) { 
   if ($row[parentid]==0) $parents[]=$row;
        else $children[]=$row;
 }

foreach($parents as $par)
{
 echo("$par[name]($par[id])<br>");
   foreach($children as $ch)
     { if ($ch[parentid]==$par[id])
                echo("->$ch[name]($ch[id])<br>");
     }
}
```

Comment: Here is one similar situation like you.. You can modify the solution and use it like your output http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306338/php-mysql-multidimensional-array-dropdown-menu/21308976#21308976

Comment: IS this actually slow??

Comment: i did not get what u mean by slow ?

Comment: What I need is a single MySQL query and a neat PHP code to process the result... Recursive sql queries are not a good way for me because I'm on a shared hosting and they don't like it.

Comment: So you have only 2 levels of data, i.e. AAA has clild BBB but BBB can never has a child or BBB can also have child ?

Comment: At the moments I'm planning to have only one level of subitems, but who knows... Of course, a universal code is preferable. My code won't work with more than one level of subitems, so I wonder if there is a better solution.

Comment: well if its more than one level then with a single query it will be fairly difficult to it, since the level may increase, for 2 levels it could be done with self join, but more than that I am afraid you either need to have stored procedure or recursive function. As long as your table is indexed with parentid and primary key it should not be a probelm with multiple queries. It does not matter if its in shared hosting, and I presume you will not have millions of records in that table.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  if ( b.parentid is null, a.name, concat( '->', a.name, ' of ', b.name ) 
    fieldname
from 
  table a 
left 
  join table b
on 
  a.parentid = b.id
order by 
  if ( b.parentid is null, a.name, b.name ), 
  a.name
```

Sorry for no format and informally response, but now i'm from mobile. Hope it works, I did it without testing, for any problem you can contact me. With this solution you can do what you want in only one query and should return results ordered.

Comment: it only works for first level children, I think recursive queries are not supported in MySQL.

Comment: It has a strange sorting behaviour when a parent has children. I have something like

`a-parent
b-parent
->a-subitem-of-c
->b-supitem-of-c
c-parent
->d-subitem-of-c
->e-subitem-of-c

**instead of**
a-parent
b-parent
c-parent
->a-subitem-of-c
->b-supitem-of-c
->d-subitem-of-c
->e-subitem-of-c`

Besides, I have no idea how to get other values from the raw such as id in my example, to write
`c-parent(id)
->a-subitem-of-c(id)
...`

Comment: Hi, I have tested it right now with the following table: `CREATE TABLE mytable (
  id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  parentid int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  name char(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (d)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;` and the following data `INSERT INTO mytable (id, parentid, name)
VALUES (1, 0, 'AAA'),(2, 0, 'BBB'),(3, 0, 'CCC'),(4, 0, 'DDD'),(5, 0, 'EEE'),(6, 0, 'FFF'),(7, 2, 'eee'),(8, 2, 'ooo'),(9, 2, 'zzz'),(10, 4, 'mmm'),(11, 4, 'nnn');`. Here the output: [link](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=24592c1) . Is it ok?

Comment: I just changed the select field in the query, here is the complete and working query: `select if ( b.parentid is null, a.name, concat( '->', a.name, ' of ', b.name ) ) fieldname, a.id, a.parentid, a.name, b.name parentName
from mytable a 
left join mytable b on a.parentid = b.id
order by if ( b.parentid is null, a.name, b.name ), a.name`

Comment: Your example works just because you added your data to the table in the correct order. But in real life, the data is not pre-sorted in the database. Truncate and try this to see what I mean: `INSERT INTO mytable (id, parentid, name) VALUES (1, 2, 'aaa'),(2, 0, 'BBB'),(3, 0, 'CCC'),(4, 0, 'DDD'),(5, 0, 'EEE'),(6, 0, 'FFF'),(7, 2, 'eee'),(8, 2, 'ooo'),(9, 2, 'zzz'),(10, 4, 'mmm'),(11, 4, 'nnn');` Besides, I don't understand how to get both name and id with your construction (to print href link based on the id)

Comment: This fixed the order problem: `order by if ( a.parentid=0, a.name, b.name ), b.name`. Perhaps I can't understand, but in the select field there is `select [...] fieldname, a.id, a.parentid, a.name, b.name parentName`, that means you're able to read (e.g. from php after the fetch of a row) that values, like you have an array like this `$array = array( 0=>array('fieldname'=>'AAA', 'id'=>1, 'parentid'=>0, 'name'=>'AAA', 'parentName'=>NULL), [...], 3=>array('fieldname'=>'->ooo of BBB', 'id'=>8, 'parentid'=>2, 'name'=>'ooo', 'parentName'=>'BBB') [...] )`. What else do you need?

Comment: I'm still not sure about sorting. `order by if ( a.parentid=0, a.name, b.name ), b.name` works with the sample database, but when I try it on my work database, I see other results. Need more time to understand what happens...

Comment: Okay. Remember that if you have 3rd level (children of children) this query doesn't work. If you send me a subset of your database maybe I can help you finding what's wrong.